# I'm following getting started with Flutter tutorials,but while running get package it gets me error

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm getting started with Flutter tutorials,but while running get package it gets me following error

```
> C:\Users\pacif\Desktop\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color packages upgrade
> Running "flutter packages upgrade" in flutter_app...            
> Error on line 26, column 8 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version constraint: > Could not parse version "flutter". Unknown text at "flutter".
>   sdk: flutter
>        ^^^^^^^
```

> pub upgrade failed (65)
>   Process finished with exit code 65

Comment: Post the content from `pubspec.yaml` that causes this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C:\Users\pacif\Desktop\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color packages upgrade

> Running "flutter packages upgrade" in flutter_app...
> Error on line 26, column 8 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version constraint: > Could not parse version "flutter". Unknown text at "flutter".
> sdk:flutter

Remove Extra Space